# Time complexity of finding longest compound word

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I am referring to the algorithm question here:

http://www.ardendertat.com/2012/06/15/programming-interview-questions-28-longest-compound-word/

> Given a sorted list of words, find the longest compound word in the
>   list that is constructed by concatenating the words in the list. For
>   example, if the input list is: ['cat', 'cats', 'catsdogcats',
>   'catxdogcatsrat', 'dog', 'dogcatsdog', 'hippopotamuses', 'rat',
>   'ratcat', 'ratcatdog', 'ratcatdogcat']. Then the longest compound word
>   is ‘ratcatdogcat’ with 12 letters. Note that the longest individual
>   words are ‘catxdogcatsrat’ and ‘hippopotamuses’ with 14 letters, but
>   they’re not fully constructed by other words. Former one has an extra
>   ‘x’ letter, and latter is an individual word by itself not a compound
>   word.

I implemented the algorithm as follows:

1. Construct a Trie out of all the words in the input list. Each node represents one character and end of a word is marked by setting `isTerminal=true`.
2. Now I have another method to examine each input word to find out number of components (let's say compound length) it is made of. For example, in the above example `ratcatdogcat` is made of individual words in the input list `rat`, `cat`, `dog` and `cat`. I do this by recursively parsing out valid prefix of input word and finding the compound length of rest of the word i.e., parse `rat` and get compound length for `catdogcat`. If the compound length of rest is `zero`, meaning rest is not a valid construct, I try the next prefix `ratcat` and recurse on `dogcat`.

Pseudo code looks like this:

```
Node {
  Character ch
  Map<Character, Node> children
  boolean isTerminal
}

int getCompoundLength(word) {

  if (dpTable.contains(word))
    return dpTable.get(word)

  dpTable.put(word, 0) // memoize word to compound length

  Node current = root;
  for (i=0 to word.length) {
    ch = word[i]
    if (!current.children.contains(ch)) // invalid character
      return 0;

    current = current.children.get(ch)

    if (!current.isTerminal) // not a valid prefix yet
      continue

    lenRest = getCompoundLength(word.substring(i+1));

    if (lenRest != 0) { // rest of the string is valid
      dpTable.put(word, lenRest+1)
      return lenRest + 1
    }
  }

  // Could not split the word into multiple components.
  // Check if word is a valid word at least.
  if (current.isTerminal) {
    dpTable.put(word, 1)
    return 1;
  }
```

I understand that constructing trie takes O(W) where W is the total number of input words. But I don't have a clear idea of how to compute the running time of `getCompoundLength` method. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is wrong.  Inserting a word into a trie has running time of the length of the word, so the time to construct the trie is `O(W*s)` where `s` is the average size of the word.

Looking for a word that is in the trie is worst case `O(s)` where `s` is the length of the word.

As for your `getCompoundLength` method, you need to come up with the most pessimistic possible input.  Consider the following example:

```
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab
```

The last word is not a compound word.  But you have just hit an exponential backtracking problem on figuring that out...

(Real world regular expression implementations have this problem in spades.  They work fine on most strings, but there are pathological inputs that make them weep.)